# Ruby: group and count the number of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I count the number of results returned by a "group" query without getting the data ? So far, I am just getting a hashtable of results. Is it possible in rails3 to optimize this query ?

```
Vote.group("question_id, user_id").where("question_id = 3").count.count
 => 2
```

In this case we are doing a count of this hashtable => `{1=>10, 15=>1}`

Query is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, question_id, user_id AS question_id_user_id
FROM `votes`
WHERE (question_id = 3)
GROUP BY question_id, user_id
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to find? The total of Votes that have both attributes, question_id, and user_id, where question_id = 3? Not sure I understand your query.

Comment: I wanna do a simple count on a group but currently I'm getting a hastable with the data and i have to do a count again to get the number of users that voted on a specific question. I'm doing a group because I can have multiple answer possible by user for a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use count_by_sql:

```
Vote.count_by_sql("select count(*) from ( select 1 from Votes group by question_id, user_id )")
```

Or, you can build up the query using Rails, and then run it:

```
 query = Vote.group(:question_id, :user_id).to_sql
 count = Vote.count_by_sql("select count(*) from ( #{query} )")
```

Comment: The workaround is working fine. On my test on mysql version I also had to named the table : `select count(*) from ( #{query} ) mycount`